# Permissions error trying to download folder from GoDaddy Website via Powershell

Tags: powershell

Has to have something to do with GoDaddy and permissions. I can access files in that folder but get 403 when trying to access the folder itself (download):

```
$outputdir = 'C:\Windows10Upgrade'
$url       = 'httx://www.mydomain.com/Windows10Upgrade/'

# enable TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.1 protocols
#[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11

$password = Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'MYPASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'MYACCOUNTNUMBER', $password

$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Credential $credential
# get the list of links, skip the first one ("../") and download the files
$WebResponse.Links | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Downloading file '$_'"
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $outputdir -ChildPath $_
    $fileUrl  = '{0}/{1}' -f $url.TrimEnd('/'), $_
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUrl -OutFile $filePath
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a GoDaddy UserID and Password add a PSCredential object to your request:

```
$password = Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'myuserid', $password

# Download a file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $target -Credential $credential
```

Substitute your UserID with myuserid and your Password with mypassword in the code above which creates the PSCredential object (called $credential) you then pass into the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet as seen in the last line.

Comment: Changed the code to above. Same 403 error.

Comment: Your last line `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUrl -OutFile $filePath` will also need the credentials